# the inverter switching point

Tags: digital-logic, analog, inverter, nmos, pmos

As we know the mobility of the "nmos" device is 3x greater than "pmos", and when we want to correct the switching point of an inverter for vdd/2 we usually change the W of the "pmos" device, We can't correct this point by changing the L of the transistor?

Comment: Please clarify the question it is hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the inverter threshold to a value desired by you by changing the W or L of PMOS or the NMOS but you must check if your design gives the optimum area, power and drive strength.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to keep the width of the PMOS and NMOS the same and increase the length of NMOS. If you do that, you will have a low drive strength inverter compared to keeping the length same and increasing the width of the PMOS.

Comment: Yes, you understood the question correctly. 

so you mean that if we change the L of the NMOS device the current of an inverter is decreased and the fan-out of the inverter is also decreased and we cannot drive as many elements as in the case of the former L right? 

Is there another reason why we don't change the L_?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason for not increasing L. In conclusion, it is better to use the minimum length for logic gate design and modify width according to the number of elements you have to drive. This is also going to reduce switching current. For reducing leakage current, sometimes L is increased but otherwise, we always go with minimum L.

Comment: And how does it reduce the switching current?

Comment: Lesser area of device means lesser gate cap and hence lesser switching current